# How to display duplicate emails count from database table?

Tags: sql

Here, this is my database table structure.

```
|----|------------------|
|SN  |     Email        |
|----|------------------|
|1   | aa@gmail.com     |
|----|------------------|
|2   | aa@gmail.com     |
|----|------------------|
|3   | bb@gmail.com     |
|----|------------------|
|4   | bb@gmail.com     |
|----|------------------|
|5   | bb@gmail.com     |
|----|------------------|
|6   | cc@gmail.com     |
|----|------------------|
```

I Want to display rows in this way:

**SN     Email                          DuplicateCount**
1       aa@gmail.com      2
2       bb@gmail.com      3
3       cc@gmail.com      1

Please suggest me how to make SQL for display duplicate emails.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `count` to get it:

```
select email, count(email) as duplicates from 
  tableName group by email order by duplicates desc
```

Answer (score 2):

Please use below SQL QUERY .

**This is SQL :** 
`` SELECT `Email`, count(Email) as DuplicateCount FROM `tablename` group by Email ``

I hope using the above SQL your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

use row_number() which suppor most dbms
and count

```
  select row_number()over(order by email) as sn
  ,email, count(*) as  DuplicateCount from 
  table_name group by email order by email
```